# jquery on click event working on all divs with same class

Tags: jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

I am having a few issues with a jquery click event and need some help.

I have an image with a plus sign. Once the user clicks this plus sign I want the background text div to fade in. The text div has a cross. So when the user clicks the cross the text div fades out and the image fades back in. If you get me?

There are a few of these boxes on the page and the issue with my code is that it triggers the fade action on all the divs. Not just the once you click on.

Here is my HTML. There are multiple of these on my page to create a portfolio block.

```
<a class="flip-container">
    <div class="flip-container">
         <div class="flipper">
               <div class="front">
                    <div class="plus"></div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio.jpg" alt="Animation">
                        <h3>Project name</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                     <div class="cross"></div>
                     <p>Some text goes here.</p>
                      <p>by persons name</p>
                </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.back').hide();
$('.flip-container .plus').click(function(e){    
    $('.front').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.back').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('.flip-container .cross').click(function(e){    
    $('.back').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.front').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: In your click handler, `this` refers to the element that was clicked. Start there, then use jQuery's traversal functions to get to the specific element you want to act upon.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the div class give the div you want this to happen on an id and change your jQuery to match it.

Comment: I need the same action to happen for all but not at the same time. So adding a ID will just mean I will add an ID to each portfolio block. So the same thing will happen.

Comment: That does not make a difference as it still targets every ID.

The HTML is generated from Wordpress so the webpage has about 4 sets of the flip-container.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $('.front'), use $(this).parent()

The .front selects all the front classes. This refers to the clicked element.

Comment: This works in that it selects only the one item but when you click the plus sign it removes the entire block. The .back txt does not fadein.

Comment: Change your code for clicking the plus to this:

$('.flip-container .plus').click(function(e){    
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});